# UIBlurEffectView smaller than autolayouted parentView although identical frame

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, uivisualeffectview

I have an `UIView` for login purposes centered in the middle of the screen. It is constrained to a 0.25 height of the surrounding view (covering the whole window)

I noticed, that if I create an `UIVisualEffectView` (via the method `blurBackgroundForView(_)`as background for the `UIView`, that it is too small (check the code how I create the `UIVisualEffectView`) although it has the same frame. 
You can see the effect, when you change the `backgroundColor` to `.greenColor`.
The View is higher than the Blureffect.

**ViewController**

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
  AnimationHelper.blurBackgroundForView(self.view)
  view.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
}
```

**blurBackgroundForView(_)**

```
static func blurBackgroundForView(view: UIView!){
  view.backgroundColor = .clearColor()
  let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)
  let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
  blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
  view.insertSubview(blurEffectView, atIndex: 0)
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, me too. Can we deconfuse us together?

Comment: Your image is really confusing, the problem probably isn't. Please clarify as best you can.

Comment: I updated the image with more information. If you dont see the frame of the BlurView, adjust your monitor settings. It is very thin =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frames are not guaranteed to be set by auto layout in `viewWillAppear`.

Try setting the blur view's frame in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` instead. Alternatively, you can directly set the autoresizing mask on your blur view so that it resizes when its superview resizes:

```
blurView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

You should also call the super method in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Calling it from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` did not change anything, but the setting the autoresizingMask did the trick.